# Newlines in Upstart env stanza

Tags: linux, environment-variables, upstart

I'm trying to set a multi-line value in an environment variable using an Upstart `env` stanza. If I create a simple upstart job that just prints the environment, then run it and inspect the logs, it looks like newlines are stripped before invoking the command.

`/etc/init/newlinetest.conf`:

```
env NO_NEWLINE='just one line'
env NEWLINE='first line
second line
third line
'

exec env
```

`/var/log/upstart/newlinetest.log` after starting the simple job:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
TERM=linux
NO_NEWLINE=just one line
NEWLINE=first line second line third line
UPSTART_JOB=newlinetest
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
```

Is it possible to set a multi-line value using the `env` stanza? I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I happen to be running on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with Upstart package version 1.5-0ubuntu7.2.

Comment: Does not look to be possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @CameronNemo. I suspect that you are correct. Going to shoot an email out to the upstart-devel mailing list to confirm.

Comment: Did you get any response on the mail list?

Comment: No I did not. I was also never able to get it to work :(